# Get total height of webView's content using Javascript

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I'm using a `UIWebView` for displaying content, in the form of an HTML string – not a website, higher than the screen of the iPhone, without needing to scroll in the webView itself, leaving that to the parent scrollView.

To achieve this, I need a way to get the total document size, including the scrollable area, to set the webView's height. I have tried a number of different Javascript solutions:

```js
(document.height !== undefined) ? document.height : document.body.offsetHeight // Returns height of UIWebView
document.body.offsetHeight // Returns zero
document.body.clientHeight // Returns zero
document.documentElement.clientHeight // Returns height of UIWebView
window.innerHeight // Returns height of UIWebView -2
document.body.scrollHeight // Returns zero
```

Is there a solution that actually works?

Current (*nonworking*) code:

```objc
[[[self.singlePost.contentText subviews] lastObject] setScrollEnabled:NO];
int content_height = [[self.singlePost.contentText stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.body.offsetHeight"] intValue];
NSLog(@"Content_height: %d", content_height);
CGRect rect = self.singlePost.contentText.frame;
rect.size.height = content_height;
self.singlePost.contentText.frame = rect;
```

Comment: Does `document.body.scrollHeight` work?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no need to use Javascript in iOS 5.0 and up - you have direct, documented access to its scrollView:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    CGFloat contentHeight = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height;
    // ....
}
```

To get the total height of the contents of the webView.

Comment: That's a much better solution! Thank you!

Comment: this is returning a much bigger value!
than actual content's height.

I have a single line in the body.
but it is returning me the same height as I set for the webview in the beginning.

Comment: This returns 0 for me!

Comment: Apparently this only works if you create the UIWebView in storyboard. Creating it solely in code caused me to get a value of 0.

Comment: This solution is not working anymore. The result is random and unpredictable. Especially for complex HTML code and CSS. See the answer from @karim instead.

Answer (score 10):

When I tried with my code, I found,

```
(1) NSLog(@"webView height: %@", [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.body.offsetHeight"]);
(2) NSLog(@"webView height: %@", [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.height"]);
```

`(1)` return the height less than the original height. But `(2)` return the actual height. My suggestion is to get the `Max` of the two.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)theWebView {
    NSLog(@"Body height: %@", [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.body.offsetHeight"]);
    NSLog(@"Doc height: %@", [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.height"]);
    NSString * javaScript = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('%@').clientHeight", kDivID];
    NSLog(@"Div height: %@",[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javaScript]);
    [self reLayout];
}

- (CGFloat) getWebViewPageHeight {
    CGFloat height1 = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.height"] floatValue];
    CGFloat height2 = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.body.offsetHeight"] floatValue]; 
    return MAX(height1, height2);   
}
```

### Output

```
Body height: 485
Doc height: 509
Div height: 485
```

Comment: Correct for 2011. But in 2017 document.body.scrollHeight can be used in Javascript.

Answer (score 6):

Where do you call your code? 
For me it returns 0 if it is called right after the loadHTMLString Method.
If I call it in the (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)theWebView delegate, I get a valid value.

```
- (void)loadHTML: (NSString *)html {
    webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    webView.delegate = self;

    NSURL *resourceURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]];
    [webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL: resourceURL];
    NSLog(@"height: %d", [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.body.offsetHeight"] intValue]); // returns 0
  }

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)theWebView {
    NSLog(@"height: %@", [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.body.offsetHeight"]); //return 2166
}
```

Comment: Ok this works great if the HTML content is getting bigger. However, if I try to update the content by calling loadHTMLString again, and the the new content happens to be shorter, document.body.offsetHeight still returns the same value. Anyone else run into this problem?

Answer (score 6):

I went with a slightly different approach, to create a <DIV> that I could key off of to get the size, because I was having no luck with inspecting document/body.

This is MonoTouch C#, but should work fine in Objective-C:

```
private const string DIV_ID = "_uiwebview_";

LoadHtmlString("<body style='background-color:#yourcolor; padding:0px; margin:0px'>" +
  "<div style='width:" + Frame.Width + "px; padding:0px; margin:0px; font-family:" + 
  font.Name + "' id=" + DIV_ID + ">" + html + "</div></body>", base_url);
```

and getting the height in LoadFinished:

```
string sheight = EvaluateJavascript("document.getElementById('" + DIV_ID +
   "').clientHeight");
```

@Jesse, this works when updating with HTML that would generate a smaller size than was previously shown.

Comment: Worked great for me