# Get device height in javascript from non full screen UIWebView

Tags: javascript, iphone, uiwebview

I try to distinguish an Iphone 5 **device** in a **non full screen** `UIWebview` (320x216) from javascript.
I am using the screen height as switch as that seems the [only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505618/detecting-iphone-5-and-any-ios-device-below-it) [way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979854/uiwebview-get-total-height-of-contents-using-javascript) to do this in javascript.

The problem is that the usual way to do this reports either 0 or the height of the `UIWebview`, not the height of the device.

```
document.body.offsetHeight //returns 216
screen.availHeight //returns 0
document.documentElement.clientHeight //returns 216
window.innerHeight //returns 216
screen.height //returns 0
```

Does anybody know of a method to do this? I unfortunately don't have control over the objective c code for the `UIWebview`.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you tried this already but `screen.availHeight` returns 568 for an iPhone 5, even when the actual `UIWebView` frame is much smaller (i.e. 216). I am on iOS 7.

Answer (score -1):

Did u used this `document.write("Total Height: " + screen.height);` `screen.height` ,
The height property returns the total height of the visitor's screen, in pixels.

Comment: `screen.height` returns 0.

Comment: Please put your code on fiddle. to help you more. Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/YRrpZ/

Comment: I cant create objective c code there. So it would not be really useful. I dont want people to open the link in ios safari and the comment that it works ok. The point is that that the javascript is loaded from a non full screen UIWebview.

Comment: See that fiddle is working fine and returns exact screen height. you might have misplaced something please check once. 'screen.height'